# Inject custom HTML tags while serving Flutter web app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a simple Flutter web application with few routes (for e.g. `/`, `/about-us`, `/product/{product_id}`, etc.). I currently use `python3 -m http.server --directory build/web --bind 0.0.0.0` to serve Flutter app.

I would like to insert route specific HTML tags - for e.g., to enable link preview generation, I would like to insert route specific [Open Graph tags](https://ogp.me/).

I understand that Flutter serves an SPA, but is there a way to inject custom HTML while serving different routes? For e.g, is it possible to write custom Python/NodeJS logic to figure out the route and modify HTML before we return it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think someone did the same here:
https://almog.io/blog/dynamic-open-graph-meta-tags-flutter-web

Comment: The website is down for me. Do you have any other similar link? Thanks.